# PHP List Structure

Tags: php

Let's say I have an array containing these items:

```
$test = array(Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6, Item7, Item8, Item9);
```

How can I print this structure using for, or foreach?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 9</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you know `for`- and `while`-loops and `echo`?

Comment: yes, I cand use that too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split the array into chunks, using [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk):

```
$chunks = array_chunk($test, 4);
```

This will give you an array containing sub-arrays of 4 items each. You could then loop through these to create the list items:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($chunks as $chunk): ?>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($chunk as $item): ?>
                    <li><?php echo htmlspecialchars($item) ?></li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

use array_chunk to split your values

```
$test = array('Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5','Item6','Item7','Item8','Item9');

$chunk = array_chunk($test, 4);

echo '<ul>';
foreach($chunk as $pieces) {
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($pieces as $item) {
        echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $test = array(Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6, Item7, Item8, Item9);
    $ChunkedTestarray = array_chunk($test, 4);
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($ChunkedTestarray as $Data) {
        echo "<li><ul>";
        for ($i = 0; $i <= count($Data)-1;) {
            echo "<li>".$Data[$i]."</li>";
            $i++;
        }
        echo "</ul></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
?>
```